# BeautifulSoup, Python 3, encoding error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have an encoding problem with BeautifulSoup. In my development environment everything works fine (Ubuntu, Python 3.4, Django development server). On the production server (Ubuntu, Python 3.4, same versions of Django and BeautifulSoup - only difference is the use of gunicorn and Nginx) I get:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 301: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The trackback shows that the problem is in the statement "BeautifulSoup(data)".

```
data = open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data/file.xml'))
data = BeautifulSoup(data)
```

It seems as if BeautifulSoup tries to use ascii but the files are utf-8 encoded. I tried different approaches I could find here at stack overflow, but most of them rely on Python 2 - but I use Python 3. I also tried something like that:

```
data = BeautifulSoup(str(data.read()))
```

But that doesn't work.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have an encoding error. You have a *de*coding error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an encoding error. You have a *de*coding error. And it is the `open()` call that is really at fault here; you didn't specify an encoding so the system default is used, and on your system that default is ASCII.

You want to pass in *bytes* to BeautifulSoup:

```
with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data/file.xml'), 'rb') as datafile:
    data = BeautifulSoup(datafile)
```

BeautifulSoup will take care of the decoding from there on out. I also switched the file handling to using a `with` statement; file objects are context managers and this way it'll be closed properly for you, in all circumstances.

Since you are opening *XML*, not HTML, you probably want to inform BeautifulSoup of that:

```
with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data/file.xml'), 'rb') as datafile:
    data = BeautifulSoup(datafile, 'xml')
```

You need LXML installed for this to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Changing the open() statement to "open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data/file.xml'), encoding="utf-8")" did the trick.

Comment: @user2496550: you can still leave the decoding to BeautifulSoup; XML files include their encoding in the tags if it deviates from UTF-8.

Comment: I have "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>" in my XML files. When I use "BeautifulSoup(datafile, 'xml')" I still get the error. Only "encoding="utf-8"" in open() works for me.

Comment: @user2496550: *What error* do you get? Is it complaining about not having `lxml` installed, perhaps? Why are you opening XML with BeautifulSoup (a *HTML* parsing library)?